# Is moving a uniform vector field through an area considered a flux change?

Tags: electromagnetism, vector-fields

F(x,y,z) is a uniform vector field defined as <0,0,c>, where c is any constant. S is an area on the x-y plane where its normal vector is defined as <0,0,1>.  Moving the vector field source towards the area or moving the area towards the source at constant velocities or at constant accelerations are considered flux changes? If yes, how? If no, why?

Comment: This question would be clearer if you mentioned whether you know how flux is defined.

Answer (score 0):

For a constant field , the flux will not change in either case as the magnitude and direction of the field at each point (be it closer or farther to the source) is same and the number of such points contained in the area is also same.